# How can I proxy API calls when serving create-react-app build locally to test PWA feature?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, create-react-app, progressive-web-apps

I have a create-react-app, and I'm proxying API calls in dev.  I'm working on allowing users to add the app as an icon on their homescreen with the beforeinstallprompt:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/

I was running into issues, and found this post which explains that I need to be running the production version to test that feature:

https://medium.com/@augustgiles8/making-your-create-react-app-a-pwa-a5e9322d487e

I followed the advice there, built my app and used the serve package to serve the static prod version locally.  That fixed the other issues I was having, but now my API requests aren't proxied.

Any ideas on how I can serve the static prod build locally and still proxy the API requests to test this PWA feature?  Or suggestions on a completely different strategy for testing this locally?